# Как добавить изображение на qgraphicsview?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qgraphicsview

Я хочу, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку можно было через диалоговое окно выбрать изображение, которое необходимо поместить на `qgraphicsview`.

Создал интерфейс, через `Qt Designer` - файл **mainwindow.ui**. На форме есть кнопка `open_im` и `qgraphicsview` - `srcGraphicsView`. после выбора изображения получаю ошибку и программа вылетает. подскажите, пожалуйста, что я не так делаю?

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap

Form, Window = uic.loadUiType("mainwindow.ui")

app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
form = Form()
form.setupUi(window)
window.show()


def open():
    fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
    pixmap = QGraphicsItem(QPixmap(fname))
    form.srcGraphicsView.addItem(pixmap)


form.open_im.clicked.connect(open)

app.exec()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Класс `QGraphicsPixmapItem` предоставляет элемент растрового изображения, который вы можете добавить в `QGraphicsScene`.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspixmapitem.html#details

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class GraphicsView(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__()
        self.resize(400, 400)

        self.scene = QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 400, 400)

        self.pic = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self.pic.setPixmap(QPixmap('Ok.png').scaled(60, 60))
        # позволяет выбирать его и перемещать
        self.pic.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        # установить смещение изображения от начала координат сцены
        self.pic.setOffset(170, 170)

        self.text = QGraphicsTextItem()
        self.text.setPlainText('Hello QGraphicsPixmapItem')
        self.text.setDefaultTextColor(QColor('#91091e'))        # для установки цвета текста
        # setPos - для установки положения текстовых примитивов относительно начала координат сцены
        self.text.setPos(130, 230)

        self.scene.addItem(self.pic)
        self.scene.addItem(self.text)
        self.setScene(self.scene)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.graphicsView = GraphicsView()
        self.open_im = QPushButton('Add image')
        self.open_im.clicked.connect(self.addImage)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.graphicsView)
        layout.addWidget(self.open_im)
        
    def addImage(self):
#        pixmap = QGraphicsItem(QPixmap(fname))
#        form.srcGraphicsView.addItem(pixmap)
        fname, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 'Open file', '.', 'Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)')
        if fname:
            pic = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
            pic.setPixmap(QPixmap(fname).scaled(160, 160))
            pic.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
            pic.setOffset(12, 12)
            self.graphicsView.scene.addItem(pic)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    demo = MainWindow() #Demo()
    demo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

решил задачу по-своему. через обращение к уже существующим объектам.

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()

pic_left = QGraphicsPixmapItem()
pic_right = QGraphicsPixmapItem()

def open_image():
    src = QGraphicsScene()
    dst = QGraphicsScene()

    ui.srcGraphicsView.setScene(src)
    ui.dstGraphicsView.setScene(dst)

    filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()[0]
    if filename:
        pic_left.setPixmap(QPixmap(filename))
        ui.srcGraphicsView.scene().addItem(pic_left)
        pic_right.setPixmap(QPixmap(filename))
        ui.dstGraphicsView.scene().addItem(pic_right)

ui.open_im.clicked.connect(open_image)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```